# Running WireMock server as a stand alone

Tags: jar, wiremock

I am trying to set up a mock server using `wireMock` as a standalone process. I downloaded the jar file and executed the following command:

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.23.2.jar --port 0
```

I had to dynamically determine a port because I am already using the default 8080 port for another program running on my machine. It gave me the port number 55142, but when I tried accessing that on the web, it gave me the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 403
Problem accessing /__files/. Reason:

Forbidden

Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: Is the Usher running the Java proces allowed to read that dir?

Comment: instead of input the http://localhost:8080
please give a real url you would like to mock like: http://localhost:8080/login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably due to the fact that you just entered http://localhost:55142
and as there are no mappings in `./mappings` directory and files in ./files directory (the same where you have your wiremock.jar file is located)

```
2019-06-04 00:10:58.890 Request was not matched as there were no stubs registered:
{
    "url" : "/"
    ...
}
```

please try call with `__admin` endpoint to see if WireMock is working
http://localhost:55142/__admin

please see also docs [here](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/) for more nice admin commands.